# Using EJS with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, ember.js

I wanted to try out some of the new stuff in JS, so I chose to do Node and Ember.js
I have read that Ember.js is agnostic to the templating engine, so I was wondering whether it supports EJS, since that is supported by node, and is quite similar to ERB, what I am used to.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Ember views just like Backbone views if you don't want to use Handlebars. However, we did a significant amount of work to make Handlebars templates update automatically when their underlying properties change. Keep in mind that if you use a template engine other than Handlebars, auto-updating (a big part of the appeal of Ember IMO) will not happen.

That being said, you can set the `template` property of any view to a function that returns a string, and it will render it to the screen.

```
var view = Ember.View.create({
  template: function() { return "Hi there!" }
});

view.appendTo('#container');
```

If you'd like more details, please see the blog post I wrote on the SproutCore
blog about why we picked Handlebars: http://blog.sproutcore.com/why-handlebars/